# How to update exact duplicates in snowflake using update statement

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table with exact duplicate records and I need to update one of the duplicate using update statement only.

Table ABT before update

| ID | PNAME | CDATE | Duplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 10-JAN-23 | NULL |
| 123 | ABC | 10-JAN-23 | NULL |
| 456 | DEF | 10-JAN-23 | NULL |
| 789 | GHI | 10-JAN-23 | NULL |

Expected result - Table ABT after update

| ID | PNAME | CDATE | Duplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 10-JAN-23 | D |
| 123 | ABC | 10-JAN-23 | NULL |
| 456 | DEF | 10-JAN-23 | NULL |
| 789 | GHI | 10-JAN-23 | NULL |

I can able to extract the duplicate with the select statement , but unable to update it.

SQL used :

```
SELECT id, pname  from 
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY cdate desc ) as dup, A.* from ABT A  
)
where dup <>1 ;
```

Comment: has your table a unique column, and when which

Comment: The unique is duplicated which is ID column. I could use the window function of row number and extract the duplicate in SQL. But unable to update the column duplicate as D.

Comment: You can use your inner query as an updatable CTE.

Comment: @Serg - But it will update both the record to column Duplicate as D right ?

Comment: if od is defined as unique you wpuldn't have the problem

Comment: select distinct ... into a new table, replace the old table with the new table.  And fix the cause of the duplicates!

Comment: No, due to  `with where dup <>1`